# Gravitational Time Dilation at height H Formula

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, time-dilation

The Wikipedia lists this formula for finding the time dilation in a gravitational field from one point to another point at "height" h, by integrating over the gravitation. However there is no derivation given and I didn't find one in any of the references. Where does this form come from?

$$T_{d}(h)=\exp \left[{\frac {1}{c^{2}}}\int _{0}^{h}g(h')\space dh'\right]$$

I'm curious because if you consider this the solution to a Volterra product integral, you can estimate the time dilation over very small "height" distances (eg Planck scale) using

$$\left(1+\frac{g(x)\cdot \Delta x}{c^2}\right)$$

However I don't know the conditions on the original equation (eg is it already an approximation, in what types of spacetime is it valid, etc)